# Time out in Sql server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My problem is, I am making android application and I parse data from services I can take data from services When I request it four times, but more than request four times service doesn't work and I can't take data from it, After one hours Services working itself and I can take data. I use Sql server 2008,  Which do I make setting in sql server??

Comment: First determine, if it is your SQL Query that is timing out or the service

Comment: I don't know server doesn't work. Do you think which one SQL Query or service